Overlay centralised dots on grouped bar chart using ggplot
I want to overlay centralised dots on grouped bar chart using ggplot, but I could not achieve that. Any help will be appreciated. Below is my code:
# Dummy data
dummy_df <- data.frame(facility = rep(c("GP", "Hospital", "Other"), each = 2),
                 enrolled = rep(c("Enrolled", "Unenrolled"), 3),
                 completed = c(3500,80,70,20,110,20),
                 per = c(0.93,0.85,0.82, 0.85, 0.50, 0.41))


# Bar-chart
ggplot(dummy_df) +
     geom_bar(aes(x = facility, y = per, group = enrolled, fill = enrolled),
              stat = "identity", position = "dodge") +
     
     geom_point(data = dummy_df, 
                aes(x = facility, y = completed/4000, fill = enrolled), size = 3,
                position = position_jitterdodge(0.3), stat="identity",
                alpha = 0.8) +
     
     labs(y = "Percentage", x = "\nFacility") +
     

     #using the scales package use the label percent to change the decimal to %
     scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::label_percent(),
                        limits = c(0,1), 
                        breaks=c(0, 
                                 0.2, 
                                 0.4, 
                                 0.6, 
                                 0.8,
                                 1.0),
                        # Add a second axis and specify its features
                        sec.axis = sec_axis(trans=~.*4000, name="Dose volume\n")) +
     # guides(fill = "none") + 
     theme(axis.text=element_text(size=12),
           legend.text=element_text(size=12),
           axis.title=element_text(size=14),
           legend.justification='left',
           legend.margin = margin(-0.2,0.5,0.1,0.1, unit="cm"),
           
           # remove title
           plot.title = element_blank(),
           
           # y-axis title
           axis.title.y.left = element_blank()
     ) 


What I want is that the black dots (which is Dose volume) on each bar is centralised.


use position_dodge(width = .9) for the points, since bar width, by default, is set to 90% of the resolution() of the data.

If you jitter with position_jitterdodge the points will be placed at random.

Instead of using position_jitterdodge(), you can use position_dodge() with the same width as the bars to ensure the points align in the middle of the bars for each group.

library(ggplot2)
library(scales)

# Dummy data 
dummy_df <- data.frame(facility = rep(c("GP", "Hospital", "Other"), each = 2),
                       enrolled = rep(c("Enrolled", "Unenrolled"), 3),
                       completed = c(3500,80,70,20,110,20),
                       per = c(0.93,0.85,0.82, 0.85, 0.50, 0.41))

# Bar-chart
ggplot(dummy_df) +
  geom_bar(aes(x = facility, y = per, group = enrolled, fill = enrolled),
           stat = "identity", position = position_dodge(width = 0.9)) +
  
  geom_point(data = dummy_df, 
             aes(x = facility, y = completed/4000, fill = enrolled), size = 3,
             position = position_dodge(width = 0.9), stat = "identity",
             alpha = 0.8) +
  
  labs(y = "Percentage", x = "\nFacility") +
  

  scale_y_continuous(labels = label_percent(),
                     limits = c(0, 1), 
                     breaks = c(0, 0.2, 0.4, 0.6, 0.8, 1.0),
                     # Add a second axis and specify its features
                     sec.axis = sec_axis(trans = ~ . * 4000, name = "Dose volume\n")) +
  
  theme(axis.text = element_text(size = 12),
        legend.text = element_text(size = 12),
        axis.title = element_text(size = 14),
        legend.justification = 'left',
        legend.margin = margin(-0.2, 0.5, 0.1, 0.1, unit = "cm"),
        
  )


Thanks Max. is it possible to make the dot appear separately as legend item?

Yes can you accept the answer . In your plot, you can use the show.legend argument in each of the geoms to control which elements appear in the legend and you can add guides() to customize  the legend. IE geom_bar(aes(x = facility, y = per, group = enrolled, fill = enrolled),
stat = "identity", position = position_dodge(width = 0.9), show.legend = TRUE)  and at the end of the code guides(fill = guide_legend(title = "Bar Legend"),
shape = guide_legend(title = "Point Legend"))
